Rigorous proof that sequence converges
I have been given the sequence $x_n=\frac{\log(3n+2)}{\log(n^2+2)}$ which has the limit $\frac{1}{2}$, and I have been tasked with proving that.
This is the first time I have ever proven a sequence, and I apologize for any glaring mistakes.
Thus, to prove convergence, I have to show that for any $\varepsilon$ > 0 there exists an $N$ such that for all $n > N$ the distance between $x_n$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ is less than $\varepsilon$.
$$\left|x_n - \frac{1}{2}\right| = \left| \frac{\log(3n+2)}{\log(n^2+2)} - \frac{1}{2}\right| < \varepsilon $$
I multiply both sides with $\log(n^2+2)$ and get :
$$\left|\log(3n+2)-\frac{\log(n^2+2}{2}\right|  < \varepsilon \log(n^2+2) $$
I now use the property of logarithms:
$$\left|\frac{3n+2}{(n^2+2)^\frac{1}{2}}\right| < e^{\varepsilon \cdot \log(n^2+2)}$$
Which I simplify to:
$$\left|\frac{3n+2}{(n^2+2)^\frac{1}{2}}\right| < (n^2+2)^\varepsilon $$
Thus, I choose $N$ such that $(n^2+2)^\varepsilon$< 1 + $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ for all $n≥N$, and for all $n≥N$ the distance between $x_n$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ is less than $\varepsilon$.

Your evaluation is fine but this is not a correct proof if your aim is to make use of the definition.

How can I improve it?

You need to esplicitely show that for any fixed $\varepsilon$ we can find $n_0$ such that for any $n\ge n_0$ the inequality is satisfied.

But isn't that what I wrote here? "$\epsilon$ > 0, simply choosing N = 1 for all n > N will do. " Can you give a hint of how I could do it properly then?

Take $n=2$ then $x_n-\frac12 \approx 0.66$ wich is not less that $\varepsilon =\frac12$.

Your solution is good up to $\frac{3+2}{(^2+2)^{1/2}}<(^2+2)^.$ Then use $\frac{3+2}{(^2+2)^{1/2}}<\frac{6n}{}=6$ (make the numerator bigger and the denominator smaller) and $n^{2}<(^2+2)^{}$ (replace the $+2$ with $+0$) to see it is sufficient to solve $6<n^{2}.$ This gives $\frac{\log(6)}{2}<\log(n)$ or equivalently $N=e^{\log(6)/2}.$

Your proof is incorrect. First of all, it reaches the wrong conclusion: it should be obvious that $\frac{1}{2}$ is not smaller than $\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon$.
So where is the proof wrong? The main problem is the assumption that "$\log(n^2+2)$ grows much faster than $\log(3n+2)$." Indeed, since $n^2+2\leq (n+2)^2$, we see that $\log(n^2+2)\leq 2\log(n+2)$, so it is definitely not "much" faster than $\log(3n+2)$.
Another way to see the problem in your proof is that if $\log(n^2+2)$ grows much faster than $\log(3n+2)$, the limit of their quotient should definitely be $0$. For the limit to be non-zero and not diverge, they have to grow at approximately the same rate.
To do the proof correctly, you'll need to actually use properties of the functions involved, in this case logarithm rules. Try to write $3n+2 = n(3+\frac{2}{n})$, and similarly for $n^2+2$, and manipulate the fraction you get after finding a common denominator.
If you want, edit your answer and write me a comment, then I'll have a look at it again.

Edit: Since you gave some proper attempts, I will provide you with a partial solution.
Your first idea was good, let us compute the absolute value of a term in the sequence, minus the limit, and let us put in on a common denominator:
$$\left|\frac{\log(3n+2)}{\log(n^2+2)}-\frac12\right| = \left|\frac{2\log(3n+2)-\log(n^2+2)}{2\log(n^2+2)}\right|.$$
Now, write $\log(3n+2)=\log(n(3+\frac{2}{n})) = \log(n)+\log(3+\frac{2}{n})$ and similarly $\log(n^2+2) = 2\log(n)+\log(1+\frac{2}{n^2})$. Inserting, we get
$$\left|\frac{2(\log(n)+\log(3+\frac{2}{n}))-(2\log(n)+\log(1+\frac{2}{n^2}))}{2(2\log(n)+\log(1+\frac{2}{n^2}))}\right| = \left|\frac{\log(3+\frac{2}{n})-\frac12\log(1+\frac{2}{n^2})}{\log(n)+\log(1+\frac{2}{n^2})}\right|.$$
The conclusion should now be intuitively clear: since the numerator is in fact decreasing in $n$, while the denominator is growing towards infinity in $n$, the whole thing will go to $0$ - and this is what we want.
However, you need to finish the proof in detail: Given an $\epsilon>0$, how do I pick $N$ such that the fraction above is less than $\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$?
If your argument does not contain some variant of the following things, it is probably wrong/not detailed enough:

Some inequality simplifying the above fraction, using properties of the logarithm.
The fact that the logarithm is a (strictly) increasing function, with limit $\infty$, or the defining property of the logarithm.


I have written a new proof using the property of logarithms. Thoughts? Is it still incorrect?

Your edited proof is still incorrect. $(n^2+2)^\epsilon$ still grows to infinity, whenever $\epsilon>0$ is fixed and $n\to \infty$. I know I mentioned using a property of the logarithm, but what I really meant was to use $\log(x^k) = k\log(x)$ and $\log(ab)=\log(a)+\log(b)$. Try again, looking at the hints in my answer.

@JamesM. If you have given it a serious try and still cannot solve it, I can provide more hints/a solution.

I would certainly appreciate a solution, since I don't have any ideas left

@JamesM. I edited my answer with a partial solution, try to fill out the details.
